# Convert a date of YYYY-mm-dd format to dd-mm format using PHP

Tags: php

I have a date: `2015-06-24`

I want to display it as `24 June`

I have written this code.

```
$evnt_start_date = date('F m', strtotime($evnt_details['events_date']));
```

It displays the result like: `June 06`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `echo date('j-m', strtotime($evnt_details['events_date']));`

Comment: Is my answer not helpful to you????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`m`  is number of month. Use `d` in reverse order:

```
$evnt_start_date = date('d F', strtotime($evnt_details['events_date']));
```

Answer (score 1):

read more about [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
<?php
    echo date('d F', strtotime($evnt_details['events_date']));
?>
```

This will output in this format  `DD-MM`

date() Formatting Methods...

```
<?php
// Assuming today is March 10th, 2001, 5:16:18 pm, and that we are in the
// Mountain Standard Time (MST) Time Zone

$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
$today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");                   // 2001-03-10 17:16:18 (the MySQL DATETIME format)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give you `24 June`.

```
date("d F",strtotime($evnt_details['events_date']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers above will work just fine for you, but I'd like to suggest a really awesome way to work with Dates and Time in PHP. It's `DateTime` and their related classes; to answer your question:

```
$dateString = '2015-06-24';
$date = new \DateTime($dateString);
$evnt_start_date = $date->format('d F');
```

See the following links:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php - DateTime

Some extra reading that will help both now and in the future:
http://www.phptherightway.com/#date_and_time - PHP the right way

Answer (score -1):

Use `j` for not leading 0 and use `d` for leading zero.

Not leading Zero:

```
$evnt_details['events_date'] = '2015-06-24';
echo $evnt_start_date = date('j F', strtotime($evnt_details['events_date']));//24 June
```

Leading Zero:

```
$evnt_details['events_date'] = '2015-06-24';
echo $evnt_start_date = date('d F', strtotime($evnt_details['events_date']));//24 June
```

Comment: nice gist for me thanks to downvote giver.